# Inheriting from OpenCV class - compiling error

Tags: c++, opencv, inheritance

i need to inherit from an openCV class. The purpose - adding a custom metric.

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"

class SomeChild : public BFMatcher
{
public:
    SomeChild(int _normType, bool _crossCheck);
    ~SomeChild();
    void knnMatchImpl( const Mat& queryDescriptors, vector<vector<DMatch> >& matches, int k, const vector<Mat>& masks=vector<Mat>(), bool compactResult=false );
};
```

I get an error:

```
error C2504: 'BFMatcher' : base class undefined
```

looking in the openCV code, the class is defined as

```
class CV_EXPORTS_W BFMatcher : public DescriptorMatcher
```

where

```
#define CV_EXPORTS_W CV_EXPORTS
#if (defined WIN32 || defined _WIN32 || defined WINCE) && defined CVAPI_EXPORTS
#  define CV_EXPORTS __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define CV_EXPORTS
#endif
```

Why am i getting this error and what do i need to do to make it work ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

are you using the 'cv' namespace? Or better yet cv::BFMatcher?

```
class SomeChild : public cv::BFMatcher
```